# Add argument to entrypoint in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I got such  a dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c", "/opt/app/wait-for-it-and-start.sh"]
```

By default with no args, it doesn't wait for anything and it starts my application.

Now from a docker-compose.yaml file, I'd like to add the arguments from environment part, eg.

```
environment:
  - MONGO_HOST=mongodb
  - MONGO_PORT=27017
command: ["$$MONGO_HOST:$$MONGO_PORT"]
```

The problem is that, after a docker-compose up --build, the wait-for-it-and-start.sh receives no args.

Can someone explain me why? How can I succeed it?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass args in docker-compose.yml rewriting the entrypoint with the parameters you need to add like the following:

```
version: '3'
    services:
      myService:
        entrypoint: 
          - /opt/app/wait-for-it-and-start.sh
          - mongodb
          - 27017
```

Comment: This is something I'd like not to do. I'd prefer to keep the original entrypoint and not overwrite it, to be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

When you have both an entrypoint and a command (whether they come from the `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml`, or `docker run` arguments) they get combined together into one command line.  In your case, this runs (quotes added)

```sh
bash -c "/opt/app/wait-for-it-and-start.sh" "$$MONGO_HOST:$$MONGO_PORT"
```

If you look at [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html), the first parameter after the text to evaluate is taken as the implicit `$0` parameter that normally holds the name of the script, which is why it's getting swallowed here.

The easiest mechanical change is to just remove the `sh -c` wrapper.  (You almost never need it, unless you need things like redirection or command chaining, and if you do, the plain-string form of *e.g.* `CMD` will insert it for you.)

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/app/wait-for-it-and-start.sh"]
```

I suspect you're counting on the shell to expand the environment variables for you here.  It's hard to make that happen with this sequence (there's nowhere you can actually insert the `sh -c` wrapper that works).  It would be easier to just use the environment variables directly in your script than to try to read them back as positional parameters.  For example

```sh
#!/bin/sh
wait-for-it.sh "$MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT"
exec "$@"
```

with the corresponding Dockerfile

```sh
...
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/app/wait-for-it-and-start.sh"]
CMD ["/opt/app/myapp"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seem that defining a command overrides the image's entrypoint.